# How do I send value from returned from async method to another async method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have tasks defined as array of objects. `getHbaseAllCountries` returns all the country codes as an array which I’m trying to store in the variable `selectedCountries`. I pass this `var selectedCountries []` to `getComponentsGraphData` to get the data. But when I `console.log(selectedCountries)` it gives me empty array `[]` though I have added a callback.

```
var tasks = [{
    func: 'getHbaseAllCountries',
    options: options
}];
var results = [];
var selectedCountries= [];
async.forEach(tasks, function(value, callback) {
    if(value["func"] === 'getHbaseAllCountries') {
        cmodel.getHbaseAllCountries( value["options"],function(err, values) {
            if (err) {
                v.send(err);
                return;
            }
            for(var index=0; index< values.length; index++){
                selectedCountries.push(values[index].key);
            }   
            console.log(selectedCountries);// prints the desired results
            callback(err,values);
        });
    }
    console.log(selectedCountries);// prints []
    cmodel.getComponentsGraphData(type, selectedCountries, value["country"], value["model"], function(err, data) {
        //console.log("Data for: " + JSON.stringify(value));
            results.push({
            _id: value["key"],
            data: data
        });
        callback(err, data);
    }); 
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        v.send(err);
        return;
    }
    v.send(results);
});
```

Comment: I would advise you to use `Promises` instead of `callbacks`. You can then simply chain the promises which resolves your problem.

Comment: Moving `getComponentsGraphData` into the `getHbaseAllCountries` callback would work. But I guess you have a reason not to do that, don't you?

Comment: @Pierre- I did the same what you suggested. Worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

You call `getComponentsGraphData` but you don't know if your request `getHbaseAllCountries` as ended. You should move your call of `getComponentsGraphData` as suggested in the comments. Also, the use of chained promises would be better.

```
if(value["func"] === 'getHbaseAllCountries') {
    cmodel.getHbaseAllCountries( value["options"],function(err, values) {
        [...]
        cmodel.getComponentsGraphData....
    }
}else{
    cmodel.getComponentsGraphData....
}
```

Comment: Yes I moved the `getComponentGraphsData` into `getHbaseAllCountries`, it worked fine!